# Issue while running a query within a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that expects a `SELECT` statement as a parameter.
If I run the SELECT Statement out of the procedure, it runs fine, but when I run it within the procedure i get the error:

The procedure :

```
data_dump(query_in => 'select * from reservation where type not in ('H','PURGE','E') ',
                               file_in      => 'export_'||months_from||''||months_to||'.csv',
                              directory_in => 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test',
                              delimiter_in => '|' );
```

The query itself gives me the expected result.

```
select * from reservation where type not in ('H','PURGE','E', '|| other ||') 


The error is: encountered the symbol 'H'.
```

Can it be because of the single quotes around the IN condition?

getting error missing right parenthesis:

```
(trunc(a.update_date) between (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(]'|| months_from ||q'[') ) from dual) and (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(]'|| months_to ||q'[') from dual))]'
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your quoting.

Comment: @mbuechmann yes, but i don't know what exactly should I do.

Comment: q-quotes should be like this: `q'[text here]'`. (You can use other delimiters, e.g. `q'{text here}'`, `q'#text here#'`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing quoted arguments within a string. You need to either escape those internal quotes:

```
data_dump(query_in => 'select * from reservation where type not in (''H'',''PURGE'',''E'') ',
                               file_in      => 'export_'||months_from||''||months_to||'.csv',
                              directory_in => 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test',
                              delimiter_in => '|' );
```

Or use the [alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA):

```
data_dump(query_in => q'[select * from reservation where type not in ('H','PURGE','E') ]',
...
```

---

With your 'other' value you need to still include that in its own escape quotes:

```
data_dump(query_in => 'select * from reservation where type not in (''H'',''PURGE'',''E'','''|| other ||''')',
...
```

or (getting less readable now, perhaps):

```
data_dump(query_in => q'[select * from reservation where type not in ('H','PURGE','E',']' || other || q'[')]',
...
```

You can use `dbms_output` to debug this sort of thing, printing the generated argument and seeing if that matches what you've been running manually.

---

With your third partial code you've put closing single quotes after the (presumably numeric) variables:

```
(trunc(a.update_date) between (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(]'|| months_from ||q'[') ) from dual) and (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(]'|| months_to ||q'[') from dual))]'
                                                                                         ^                                                                            ^
```

and you are, as the message says, missing a closing parenthesis in the second `add_month` call; so it should be (where `...` is the rest of the statement that you haven't shown):

```
q'[ ... (trunc(a.update_date) between (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(]'
  || months_from ||q'[) ) from dual) and (select add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -(]'
  || months_to ||q'[) ) from dual))]'
```

Again, this is basic debugging you can do by printing the generated statement and inspecting it or trying to run it manually.

Also you don't need the inner `select from dual` stuff or all the parentheses; you can just do:

```
q'[ ... trunc(a.update_date) between add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -]'
  || months_from ||q'[) and add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -]'|| months_to ||q'[)]'
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, the problem with this is that i am also trying to pass a parameter, and it converts everything to string. It is my fault I didn't say it earlier. I'll update the question.

Comment: @A.D - updated to show how to wrap that in its own escaped quotes.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I tried the last method but I am getting a missing right parentheses. I updated the question and put only the condition of the select statement, can you help me to find where the mistake is? I am not sure I used the q'[]' correctly